# How to turn rownames of a dataframe in format `col1 + col3 + col4` into a column of numerical vectors `c(1,3,4)`?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How to turn rownames of a dataframe in format `col1 + col3 + col4` into a column of numerical vectors `c(1,3,4)`? The data frame looks like:

[image: dataframe]

I tired:

```
> bel_bpa_df <- rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(bel_bpa), var = "SNPs") %>% 
+   mutate(SNPs = str_split(SNPs, "\\+")) %>%
+   mutate(SNPs = unlist(SNPs)) %>%
+   mutate(SNPs = parse_number(SNPs))
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `SNPs = unlist(SNPs)`.
✖ `SNPs` must be size 30 or 1, not 4944.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

but I don't understand the error. Why can't I use unlist? Can anyone provide how to understand the error at a deeper level? i.e. where's my lack of knowledge about this package or how R works or how Regex works? I'm not looking for a quick fix.

Comment: `parse_number` only accept vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowname = str_extract_all(rowname, "\\d+"))
   rowname v1 v2
1 1, 3, 67  1  3
2 4, 5, 77  3  4
3    12, 6  5  9
```

Here we use `str_extract` to match and extract only the `d`igits from the column `rowname`; the comma separator is added automatically to the extracted list

Test data:

```
test <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,3,5),
                   v2 = c(3,4,9))
row.names(test) <- c("col1 + col3 + col67", "col4 + col5 + col77", "col12 + col6")
```

**EDIT**:

To cast the data frame longer on `rowname`, thereby being able to convert it to numeric, use `unnest_longer`:

```
test %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowname = str_extract_all(rowname, "\\d+")) %>% 
  unnest_longer(rowname) %>%
  mutate(rowname = as.numeric(rowname))
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  rowname    v1    v2
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1     3
2       3     1     3
3      67     1     3
4       4     3     4
5       5     3     4
6      77     3     4
7      12     5     9
8       6     5     9
```

`str_extract_all` is a highly useful regex-sensitive function; it can be used to yank out, or 'extract', substrings form larger strings.

Comment: is there an easy way to convert the vector of extracted numeric (which in this case `character`) to `numeric` type vector?

Comment: No easy way as `rowname` is a list but see edited solution with `unnest_longer`

Comment: The result isn't a numeric vector. I need numeric vector like `list(c(1,3,167),c(4,5,77),c(12,16))` for `rowname` column. Is there a way this is gonna work?

Comment: The result of the edited solution **is** numeric; check with `str`.

Comment: Oh that's just a mistake. I can only undo that in 8 min.

Comment: Actually you'll have to edit it a little bit. Can you do that?

Comment: Also would be good if you can add what got you think of `str_extract_all`

Comment: `str_extract_all` is a highly useful regex-sensitive function; it can be used to yank out, or 'extract', substrings form larger strings.

Comment: If I would like to do this on more complex strings except they're separated by + sign, is there a way I can modify this answer to accept such an input?

Comment: For instance `1:55018503_GT_G + rs1084150 + rs299859`

Comment: Sorry, too far off the original q: Please ask new q